# how to change the browser url when clicked on an anchor link using Iframe in asp

Tags: html, asp-classic

This secure website is using IFrames https://www.said.net/secure/mcrostie/index-shop.asp. My requirement is to only keep the transaction pages secure. I changed the landing page to http://www.said.net/secure/mcrostie/index-shop.asp but kept the 'Account','Cart','CheckOut'  links secure (this can be seen by hovering over the Account, Cart and Checkout links). All seems to be working fine but as secure pages are linked via IFrame, the landing URL does not change to Https when the user clicks on these links. how can we force the browser to show https instead of http

Comment: Please clarify if you're using ASP.NET or Classic ASP. You've used both tags. (Classic ASP uses the `.asp` file extension and hasn't been updated since version 3.0 in Windows 2000).

Comment: Sorry I m using classic ASP

Comment: Please read this Bob: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 0):

simply change all the links going to your transaction pages to use https, and all the other links for the rest of your site to use http.

Comment: This is what i tried to do. But the problem is that because of the IFrames the URL won't show up in the browser

Comment: there isnt any way around that, the browser will only show what it knows about in the context, it knows nothing about the iframe, all it knows is it is not on a page that is using https. removing your iframe might be the best option then. i cant think of a reason you have a problem with using https across the whole sight?